# T-SQL query producing different output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two code snippets which are producing different outputs. Please can anyone suggest where I am making the mistake?

First code snippet:

```
select 
    a.contest_id,
    B.hacker_id,
    B.name,
    SUM(e.total_submissions)total_submissions,
    SUM(e.total_accepted_submission) total_accepted_submission,
    SUM(total_view)total_view,
    SUM(total_unique_views) total_unique_views 
from  
    Contests b 
inner join 
    Colleges a on A.contest_id = B.contest_id
left join  
    Challenges c on a.college_id = c.college_id 
left join 
    (select 
         challenge_id,
         SUM(total_views) total_view,
         sum(total_unique_views) total_unique_views 
     from 
         View_Stats 
     group by challenge_id) d on c.challenge_id = d.challenge_id 
left join 
    (select 
         challenge_id,
         SUM(total_submissions) total_submissions,
         SUM(total_accepted_submission) total_accepted_submission 
     from  
         Submission_Stats 
     group by 
         challenge_id) e on e.challenge_id = d.challenge_id
group by 
    a.contest_id, b.hacker_id, B.name 
having 
    (sum(total_submissions) +
    sum(total_accepted_submission) +
    sum(total_view) + sum(total_unique_views)) <> 0
order by
    a.contest_ID
```

Second code snippet:

```
;WITH SUM_View_Stats AS 
(
    SELECT 
        challenge_id,
        total_views = SUM(total_views),
        total_unique_views = SUM(total_unique_views)
    FROM 
        View_Stats 
    GROUP BY 
        challenge_id
)
, SUM_Submission_Stats AS  
(
    SELECT 
        challenge_id,
        total_submissions = SUM(total_submissions),
        total_accepted_submissions = SUM(total_accepted_submission)
    FROM 
        Submission_Stats 
    GROUP BY 
        challenge_id
)
SELECT  
    con.contest_id, con.hacker_id, con.name,
    SUM(total_submissions),
    SUM(total_accepted_submissions),
    SUM(total_views),
    SUM(total_unique_views)
FROM 
    Contests con
INNER JOIN 
    Colleges col ON con.contest_id = col.contest_id
INNER JOIN 
    Challenges cha ON cha.college_id = col.college_id
LEFT JOIN 
    SUM_View_Stats vs ON vs.challenge_id = cha.challenge_id
LEFT JOIN 
    SUM_Submission_Stats ss ON ss.challenge_id = cha.challenge_id
GROUP BY 
    con.contest_id, con.hacker_id, con.name
HAVING 
    (SUM(total_submissions) +
     SUM(total_accepted_submissions) +
     SUM(total_views) + 
     SUM(total_unique_views)) <> 0
ORDER BY
    con.contest_ID
```

The problem is in value of total submissions and total_accepted_submission

Comment: Can you share what kind of difference?

Comment: 1. You can help us and provide some sample data script. 2. What problem you have, different result, error exception, performance issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You have `LEFT JOIN Challenges` in the first example and `INNER JOIN Challenges` in the second one.